# How to send value from viewControllerA to viewControllerB?

Tags: ios, objective-c

A `UIButton` with title `---> Free Coins - Press <----` on `viewControllerA` is pressed.

`viewControllerA`:

```
- (IBAction)triggerVideo
{
    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"HIDDEN-CODE-PRIVACY" withDelegate:nil
        withV4VCPrePopup:YES andV4VCPostPopup:YES];
}
```

50 coins are gained when it's clicked:

```
// Get currency balance from persistent storage and display it
- (void)updateCurrencyBalance
{
    NSNumber* wrappedBalance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        objectForKey:kCurrencyBalance];
    NSUInteger balance = wrappedBalance && [wrappedBalance isKindOfClass:
        [NSNumber class]] ? [wrappedBalance unsignedIntValue] : 0;
    [currencyLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", balance]];
}
```

But these coins must only show up on `viewControllerB`, on the label called `lblpts`. Or at least show up on both as the same values!

I've tried to use ints: e.g. `int point`, and `objectForKey:@"point"`, e.g.:

```
savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

nPoint = [[savedStock objectForKey:@"point"] intValue];
[_lblpts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",nPoint]];
```

But it seems, I can't make the balance appear only on the `viewControllerB` label!

Comment: What's in the file at `path`?  What's in `savedStock` after you init it?

Comment: I'd wait with the coins until the ad is finished :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a property variable in `viewControllerB` and while pushing `viewControllerB` initialize that variable with points.

If you are using storyboard then:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueB" sender:self];
```

In `prepareForSegue` method update the property variable with latest points.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueB"]) {
        DetailVCB *detailB = (DetailVCB *)segue.destinationViewController;
        detailB.points = 50; // the variable which has latest points.
    }
}
```

If you are using XIB then you can achieve it adding this in `ViewControllerA.m`:

```
ViewB *ScreenB = [[[ViewB alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewBNib" bundle:nil]
    autorelease];
ScreenB.points = balance; //balance is the variable having latest points
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ScreenB animated:YES];
```

In `ViewControllerB.h` file add the property declaration as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger points;
```

In `ViewControllerB.m` file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", self.points];
    [self.pointsLbl setText:str];
}
```

Comment: Could you please give an example?

@property IBOutlet UILabel* currencyLabel; ?

B to B or did you mean A to B?

Comment: No I'm not using story board!

Comment: You can also use NSUserDefault to store and retrieve the same in ViewControllerB. Are you using XIB?

Comment: detailB.points = balance; // the variable which has latest points? because the coins are coming from a different server!

Comment: yes, you can use detailB.points = balance.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reflect for XIB also

Comment: Should I edit some of the code highlight in blue! Should I implement this into the ViewController B, where the coins will show?

Comment: You only need to declare a property variable in ViewControllerB.h file and while pushing ViewControllerB file update the variable with actual value. In ViewDidLoad() method of ViewControllerB using this variable update the UILabel.

Comment: I'm getting an error on auto release

Comment: Didnt work, even if you wanted it to

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom delegate method or notification center method for passing data between two view controller's. Also using property is also good way for passing data but if you got a lot of info to pass from one view controller to another then you should go for custom delegate method.

Comment: hey much appreciated an example would help too ?

Comment: [custom delegate](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002) check out this example.

Comment: @Jking vote up or choosing it as right answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a forward message passing from `viewControllerA` to `viewControllerB`. This can be easily achieved with a simple method below:

Let's say you have a method in `viewControllerB`:

```
- (void)UpdatepPoints:(int)pts {
    _point = pts;
}
```

Now in your `viewControllerA`, you just have to do something like this:

```
ViewControllerB *vc = [ViewControllerB alloc] init];
[vc UpdatepPoints:pointshere];
```

That's all. Use point property of `ViewControllerB` for getting points.

Comment: but while pushing the ViewControllerB again one more instance of ViewControllerB will be created in that instance the points variable will not be updated. Hence can't do just by allocating an instance of ViewControllerB.

Comment: Should I make two labels and pass points from one the label in VC-A to the Label in VC-B. Or can I just Make it appear in VC-B with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to broadcast coin update event. So your code would seems like:

```
- (IBAction)triggerVideo
{
    [AdColony playVideoAdForZone:@"HIDDEN-CODE-PRIVACY" withDelegate:self
        withV4VCPrePopup:YES andV4VCPostPopup:YES];
}
```

Note here `delegate` is `self`. Now implement `delegate` like:

```
- (void)onAdColonyV4VCReward:(BOOL)success currencyName:(NSString*)currencyName
    currencyAmount:(int)amount inZone:(NSString*)zoneID
{       
    NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:amount];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:
        @"kCoinUpdateNotification" object:number];
}
```

And listen for this notification in `viewControllerB` like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(
    updateCurrencyBalance:) name:@"kCoinUpdateNotification" object:nil];
```

And function implementation goes like:

```
- (void)updateCurrencyBalance:(NSNotification*)_notifObject
{
    NSNumber *wrappedBalance = [_notifObject object];
    NSUInteger balance = wrappedBalance && [wrappedBalance isKindOfClass:
        [NSNumber class]] ? [wrappedBalance unsignedIntValue] : 0;
    [currencyLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", balance]];
}
```